# solving equations in parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, solver

I have two systems I'd like to resolve in parallel to save time (in the same session: K, V and J are stored in the workspace).

```
syms a b
[a,b]=solve([K==a*V+b,D==a*J+b],[a,b])

syms c d
[c,d]=solve([3K==c*V+d,5D==c*J+d],[c,d])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried putting them together into a single set of equations...? I'm not sure it will be faster, though, symbolic math in matlab is odd.

Comment: [`parfor`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html)?

Comment: How would you use parfor here?